# How to JOIN with ON CASE in Codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I want to use CASE in JOIN condition, but it's not working anymore.

```
$this->db->join('user_profile ON sender.user_id = CASE WHEN mailbox.sender_user_id = 1 
                             THEN mailbox_recipient.recipient_user_id
                             ELSE mailbox.sender_user_id END');
```

Showing ERROR like this

```
JOIN `user_profile ON sender`.`user_id = CASE WHEN mailbox`.`sender_user_id = 1 THEN mailbox_recipient`.`recipient_user_id ELSE mailbox`.`sender_user_id` `END`
```

a single quote ``` disorganized

Comment: add `(` before `CASE` and `)` after `END`

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. $this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id'); https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: @438sunil : Yeah, My bad. But its still not working if using JOIN with CASE in Codeigniter query builder. Except using $this->db->query();

Answer (score 1):

Add this before join statement

```
$this->db->protect_idenifiers(FALSE);
```

It will remove the bacticks. After you query's get() statement add the following.

```
$this->db->protect_idenifiers(TRUE);
```

to avoid security issues.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use other alternatives,

```
$this->db->join('user_profile AS sender', 'sender.user_id = '.$this->table_name.'.sender_user_id');
$this->db->join('user_profile AS recipient', 'recipient.user_id = '.$this->table_name.'_recipient.recipient_user_id');
```

then in my SELECT like this :

```
$this->db->select(
      $this->table_name.'.*, 
      (CASE WHEN mailbox.sender_user_id = '.$this->user_id.' THEN recipient.fullname ELSE sender.fullname END) AS user_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add () in case statement :

```
$this->db->join('user_profile ON sender.user_id = (CASE WHEN mailbox.sender_user_id = 1 THEN mailbox_recipient.recipient_user_id
ELSE mailbox.sender_user_id END)');
```